# How do I pass an array into a method to convert a double to a string?

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3KXd.png)I'm working on the convertToLetterGrade portion. I'd like to figure out how to pass my array into the string in order to output the minimum and maximum grade as a letter, the comments here are helpful, and I also need the gpa passed through in order to output a letter grade for that as well

public class WesternGPACalc {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //TODO:
    //declare an array to hold the grades you earned in your classes
    //feel free to use fake values
    //declare at least 4 grades
    //use a 0.0 - 4.0 scale...
    //4.0 = A, 3.5 = A/B
    //3.0 = B, 2.5 = B/C 
    //2.0 = C
    //1.0 = D
    //0.0 = F
    //for example...
    double[] grade = new double[4];
    grade[0] = 4.00; // A
    grade[1] = 2.50; // B/C
    grade[2] = 2.00; // C
    grade[3] = 1.00; // D


    //TODO:
    //use a method to print the min and max grades as letter grades
    //printGradeStats(grade);

    printGradeStats(grade);
    //TODO:
    //declare an array to hold the credits each class was worth
    //the indices must match the grade[i] indices for the class
    //for example...
    int[] credit = new int[4];
    credit[0] = 3;
    credit[1] = 3;
    credit[2] = 3;
    credit[3] = 3;        

    //TODO:
    //use a method to calculate and print the GPA as both
    //a number and a letter grade
    //pass both the credit and grade arrays to the method
    //printGPA(grade, credit);
    printGPA(grade, credit);
}

//TODO:
//Finish this method which will accept an array of grades
//and print the min and max letter grade
private static void printGradeStats(double[] grade){

    //TODO:
    //First determine the min and max letter grade...

    double minGrade = 0;
    double maxGrade = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < grade.length; i++) {
        if(grade[i] < minGrade) {
            minGrade = grade[i];
        }
        if(grade[i] > maxGrade) {
            maxGrade = grade[i];
        }
    }
    //TODO:
    //convert the min and max grades to a letter grade...
    //using your convertToLetterGrade(grade) method
    //For example...
    //String maxLetterGrade = convertToLetterGrade(maxGrade);
    String maxLetterGrade = convertToLetterGrade(maxGrade);
    String minLetterGrade = convertToLetterGrade(minGrade);
    //TODO:
    //Output them... 
    System.out.println("Max grade earned in a class was " + maxLetterGrade);
    System.out.println("min grade earned in a class was " + minLetterGrade);
}

//TODO:
//Finish this method which will convert
//a grade on the 4.0 scale and return a letter grade
//Use the following scale...
//A = 4.0
//4.0 > A/B >= 3.5
//3.5 > B >= 3.0
//3.0 > B/C >= 2.5
//2.5 > C >= 2.0
//2.0 > D >= 1.0
//F < 1.0
private static String convertToLetterGrade(double grade){

    String letterGrade = "F";


    return letterGrade;

}


//TODO:
//Finish this method which will accept an array of grades and credits
//and print the cumulative GPA as a letter grade
private static void printGPA(double[] grade, int[] credit){

    //Recall...GPA is just a weighted average...
    //Cumulative GPA is the sum of all grade points -- grade[i] * credit[i]
    //divided by the sum of all credits[i]       
    double sumCredits = 0;
    //TODO:
    //Calculate cumulative GPA      


    for (int n = 0; n < credit.length; n++) {
        sumCredits += credit[n];
    }

    double gpa = ((grade[0] * credit[0]) + (grade[1] * credit[1]) + (grade[2] * credit[2]) + (grade[3] * credit[3])) / sumCredits;
    //TODO:
    //Output Cumulative GPA as both a number and a grade
    System.out.println("Cumulative GPA " + gpa);        
    System.out.println("Cumulative GPA as a letter grade: ");
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're looking for.  You have a lot of code and the question is unspecific at a glance.  As a credit to you, the code *runs*, and it might be obvious why parts aren't correct, but you should go to elaborate what *specific* parts you need help with.

Comment: Id like to use the convertToLetterGrade method in order to show this output: Max grade: A, min grade D, cumulative gpa 2.375, cumulative gpa as letter grade C.     So I'd like to pass minLetterGrade, maxLetterGrade, and GPA through and have it output letter grades based on their values of a double

Comment: I added an image to show what I need my output to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve it by using `if-else` block as following

```
private static String convertToLetterGrade(double grade){
        String letterGrade="";
        if(grade == 4.0){
            letterGrade="A";
        }else if(grade >=3.5 && grade < 4){
            letterGrade="A/B";
        }else if(grade >= 3.0 && grade < 3.5){
            letterGrade="B";
        }else if(grade >= 2.5 && grade < 3.0){
            letterGrade="B/C";
        }else if(grade >= 2.0 && grade < 2.5){
            letterGrade="C";
        }else if(grade >= 1.0 && grade < 2.0){
            letterGrade="D";
        }else if(grade < 1.0){
            letterGrade="F";
        }
        return letterGrade;
 }
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I was trying String letterGrade; and I couldn't figure it out for the life of me, due tomorrow morning, so thank you very much!

Comment: My output shows minGrade as "F", it should say D, any ideas where this error is coming from?

Comment: what are your passing in minGrade? is it 1.0?

Comment: Yes. It should result as "D"

Comment: it's because you are initializing your minGrade as 0 so no grade would be less than 0 so it would stay as zero, so it displays F according to `zero` so now you should initialize your minGrade variable to 4.0 as `double minGrade = 4.0;`

Answer (score 0):

I see you have an answer, but let me enhance the code a little bit.

When you are calculating the cumulative GPA, You hard code the summation. You can actually use the same loop you have used to get the `sumCredits` for that, and it is the correct way to do it (Otherwise you can only check/consider 4 elements/grades).

```
double gpa = 0.0;
for (int n = 0; n < credit.length; n++) {
    gpa += grade[n] * credit[n];
    sumCredits += credit[n];
}

gpa /= sumCredits;
```

One thing in Logic,

```
    double minGrade = 5.0; // Or any max value, because you are going to find minimum values that this default one
    double maxGrade = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < grade.length; i++) {
        if(grade[i] < minGrade) {
            // if you set `double minGrade = 0` this if never becode true since every grade is greater than `0`
            minGrade = grade[i];
        }
        if(grade[i] > maxGrade) {
            maxGrade = grade[i];
        }
    }
```